# Trying to make a command-shell based 2D "character controller", unfortunately there is a "teleportation" bug

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was making a 2D character controller. So basically, you can move around. Pressing key "a" is for going left and "d" for right. It works, but there is a little problem with going right after going left. It seems to "teleport" to the last position where "d" has been clicked. Is there any solution to my code, or maybe is there a more effecient way of doing it? Thanks.

```
import os
import time

space = " "
pos = "Undefined"

import keyboard
print("■")

while True:
    if keyboard.read_key() == "d":
        os.system('cls')
        space=(space+" ")
        pos = (f"{space}■")
        print(pos)
        
    elif keyboard.read_key() == "a":
        os.system('cls')
        pos = pos[:-2]
        pos = (f"{pos}■")
        print(pos)
```

Comment: Your `space` variable doesn't change when going left, so it will continue to have its old value the next time you move right.  I'd recommend that you represent the position as an `int` instead of a `str`, then build up the string to display after modifying your characters numeric position

Comment: It works better, bug's gone too!! Thanks so much